# Getting an invalid password response using requests but the password works with manual login

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get some information from my account by using the requests library. I get a 200 response, but the content returned indicates the username/password provided in the auth is incorrect. However, I've double checked and this login information is correct as I can manually log into the website with it. Anything else I can try here? Thanks.

So when I do this...

```
request = requests.request("GET", 'https://www.usmobile.com/', auth=(MY_USERNAME, MY_PASSWORD))
```

It returns...

```
<Response [200]>
```

But looking within the response returned from...

```
request.content
```

I see the following text...

```
<p class="input error"> Invalid Email or Phone # and/or Password </p>
```

I get the same error message when I log into the website manually with an incorrect password -- "Invalid Email or Phone # and/or Password".

Comment: Are you sure url is correct?, What happens when you give incorrect password on web login

Comment: Without any information about the service we can only guess into the blue.

Comment: About the service? Do you mean the URL I'm hitting? It's this website I'm working with if that helps - https://usmobile.com

Comment: Re: the URL, I am positive it's correct, I get the same message I see in the request content when I give an incorrect password on web login -- "Invalid Email and/or Password"

Comment: It's probably expecting the auth variable to be in the POST data, but you are using GET

Comment: Hm I tried with POST instead and I get the same error within the content:
`request = requests.request("POST", 'https://www.usmobile.com/', auth=(MY_USERNAME, MY_PASSWORD))`